# Constant integer Attributes in Python Module written in C

Tags: python, c, module, constants

I implemented a python extension module in C according to https://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/extending.html

Now I want to have integer constants in that module, so I did:

```
module= PyModule_Create(&myModuleDef);
...
PyModule_AddIntConstant(module, "VAR1",1);
PyModule_AddIntConstant(module, "VAR2",2);
...
return module;
```

This works. But I can modify the "constants" from python, like

```
import myModule
myModule.VAR1 = 10
```

I tried to overload `__setattr__`, but this function is not called upon assignment.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't define module level "constants" in Python as you would in C(++). The Python way is to expect everyone to behave like responsible adults. If something is in all caps with underscores (like [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) dictates), you shouldn't change it.

Comment: C does not support symbolic constants of arbitrary type. It is not C++. Only  enum-constants are possible, but those are always `int`. And in Python, you _could_ change the setter for an object. But normally one avoids the effort and relies on the convention.

Comment: @Olaf - True, but in this case the OP is trying to prevent a reference from rebinding, which isn't possible in Python at all. And since Python integers are all immutable objects, `__setattr__` is immaterial.

Comment: Yes, that would require a "normal" class with all the overhead involved. That's why I agree about relying on the convention (if that was not clear from my comment).

Comment: It is indeed possible, if the module is replaced with an instance of custom class, but yeah, I wouldn't do it either. Also, `import math; math.PI = 3`